# Getting a '0' response when trying to do a norm.dist calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, normal-distribution

I am trying to calculate using the norm.dist function in Excel, with an x of 1044.24, a mean of 968.48, a standard deviation of 424.68 and setting to FALSE. However when I use all of these inputs I am getting a return of '0' for some reason.

Any idea what the issue may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue. You got that answer because its correct. Perhaps you need to show more digits in your cell?

`Norm.Dist(x,m,s,0)` gives you the value of the probability density function of the normal distribution function, evaluated at **x**, with mean=m and standard deviation = s. For the values of x, m and s, as given in your example, this is:

exp((x-m)^2/(2*s^2))/sqrt(2*pi*s^2)=0.000925 (approximately).

What were you expecting, or more likely, what were you trying to calculate in the first place?

[image]

Comment: You're right. I am actually trying to calculate the 95% certainty range for this data set...(828.3316667
725.2412121
527.3904918
1233.954286

686.0268254
1457.3375
1433.91493
1517.836974
1672.356933

583.5964407
423.9588393
531.7850995
779.97185
)

Comment: mean of 968.48, standard deviation of 1,044.24 as well.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @user273287 Go here https://www.mccallum-layton.co.uk/tools/statistic-calculators/confidence-interval-for-mean-calculator/#confidence-interval-for-mean-calculator Im guessing you want a confidence interval for the mean, right?

Comment: @user273287 the correct place for this type of question is actually http://stats.stackexchange.com/ by the way, in case you cannot find your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer of your function `=NORMDIST(1044.24, 968.48, 424.68, FALSE)` is `0.000924565616903431`
You can find this answer by increasing the decimal places shown in the number formatting box of the ribbon.